# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change identity of an already logged in user in realm

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting the following error while login
Cannot change identity of an already logged in user in realm 'AdapterAuthRealm'. The application must logout first.

> FWLSE0101E: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change identity of an already logged in user in realm 'AdapterAuthRealm'. The application must logout first.

My Code is as follows

Adapter.js

```
 function submitAuthentication(username, password){ 
    serversession = storeSession(username); 
    if (username!=""){

        var userIdentity = {
                userId: username,
                displayName: username, 
                attributes: {
                    foo: "bar"
                }
        };

        WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", userIdentity);

        return { 
            authRequired: false 
        };
    }

    return onAuthRequired(null, "Invalid login credentials");
 }

function onLogout(){    
    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", null);
    WL.Logger.debug("Logged out");  
 }
```

Client side

WL.Client.logout('AdapterAuthRealm', {onSuccess:WL.Client.reloadApp});

Answer (score 1):

Before:
`WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", userIdentity);`

Add:
`WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", null);`

This will make sure you have a clean slate before login in the user.

The the end result is:

```
function submitAuthentication(username, password) {
  serversession = storeSession(username);
  if (username !== "") {

    var userIdentity = {
      userId: username,
      displayName: username,
      attributes: {
        foo: "bar"
      }
    };

    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", null);
    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", userIdentity);

    return {
      authRequired: false
    };
  }

  return onAuthRequired(null, "Invalid login credentials");
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution. Result causes app going to infinite loop. Where ever we navigating it is redirected to homepage

Comment: Then I think something else is wrong in your application. Maybe in your challenge handler or app logic.